# How to always enable debug in a Python Cmd2 App?

Tags: python, cmd2

I am using the Cmd2 module in Python (version 1.0.2) to build a command-line interface (CLI).

After I run the program (so that I am inside my custom CLI), if I want debugging to be enabled so that it shows stack traces on errors, I have to manually run "set debug true" from the CLI.

What I want is a way to automatically set the "debug" flag to true every time the CLI is invoked. I know I can pass scripts to the CLI that include setting debug as the first step, but I want interactive sessions to also have this behavior.

Is there any way to change the default value for debug in Cmd2?

Comment: Does this help? [cm2 settings - debug](https://cmd2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/settings.html?highlight=debug#debug)

Comment: I found that site too but unless I'm missing something it is just documenting the "set debug true" option that a user of the CLI can type, not a way to ask for that value to be set from the python code building the CLI. Or am I reading it incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`cmd2` docs about settings](https://cmd2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/settings.html?highlight=debug#settings) say (emphases mine):

> ## Settings
>
> Settings provide a mechanism for a user to control the behavior of a `cmd2` based application. **A setting is stored in an instance attribute on your subclass of `cmd2.Cmd`** and must also appear in the `cmd2.Cmd.settable` dictionary. **Developers may set default values for these settings** and users can modify them at runtime using the set command.

So, to enable the [`debug` setting](https://cmd2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/settings.html?highlight=debug#debug) by default, you just have to set the `debug` attribute of your `cmd2.Cmd` object to `True`. For example, if this is the app:

```py
import cmd2

class App(cmd2.Cmd):
    @cmd2.with_argument_list()
    def do_spam(self, args):
        raise Exception("a sample exception")
```

you just have to do

```py
app = App()
app.debug = True
```

Now, if I run the app from the command line, `debug` will be enabled by default.

---

Full Python code:

```py
import cmd2


class App(cmd2.Cmd):
    @cmd2.with_argument_list()
    def do_spam(self, args):
        raise Exception("a sample exception")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = App()
    app.debug = True
    sys.exit(app.cmdloop())
```

Input:

```
spam
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]\venv\lib\site-packages\cmd2\cmd2.py", line 1646, in onecmd_plus_hooks
    stop = self.onecmd(statement, add_to_history=add_to_history)
  File "[...]\venv\lib\site-packages\cmd2\cmd2.py", line 2075, in onecmd
    stop = func(statement)
  File "[...]\venv\lib\site-packages\cmd2\decorators.py", line 69, in cmd_wrapper
    return func(cmd2_app, parsed_arglist, **kwargs)
  File "[...]/main.py", line 7, in do_spam
    raise Exception("a sample exception")
Exception: a sample exception
EXCEPTION of type 'Exception' occurred with message: 'a sample exception'
```